# How to create Count if and average formula together

Tags: excel-formula

For example:

> count if cell d12,d16,d20,d24 are greater then zero

take that number and then divide it by

> d12,d16,d20,d24 to get the average of those four cells, even if one or more cells have zero in them.

This has to be done to get weekly and monthly average headcount.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
=(D12+D16+D20+D24)/(1*(D12>0)+1*(D16>0)+1*(D20>0)+1*(D24>0))
```